# The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-6

Whenever I upload a huge file to the server (10MB). I get the following error on FireFox:

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

I am using Classic ASP on a Windows 2003 machine running IIS6.
Does anyone know why this is happening, and what a work around is?

Comment: How are you uploading it, and why don't you use FTP?

Comment: This works fine with other browsers?

Comment: @Malfist It's a page on our site that let's users upload a picture of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [`AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed`](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a6401b5e-c902-4035-90aa-ee46c270d357.mspx?mfr=true) Metabase Property is set below and that disconnects you.

Comment: I changed that and set it to 1GB but I still keep getting that error.